# Symfony 3 GitLab CI SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, symfony, gitlab-ci

*Feel free to give an advice about CI because I am newbie about CI.*

I have symfony (4) application and it is working good in production server. After that I wanted to write CI file for this project. But I got an error from MySQL (5.7).

I checked MySQL linked to main container also I am pretty sure what I am doing.

I used remote MySQL server but I got same error again.

I got the error in this line

`...php bin/console doctrine:schema:create...`

this is .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: php:7.1-cli

services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_USER: user_master
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_DATABASE: db_master
  DATABASE_URL: mysql://user_master:secret@mysql:3306/db_master

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install -yqq libicu-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libmcrypt-dev zlib1g-dev
  - docker-php-ext-configure intl
  - docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl dom xmlrpc xsl pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mcrypt zip
  - docker-php-ext-enable opcache

after_script:
  - php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force

build:app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-suggest --optimize-autoloader --quiet
    - rm -rf /usr/local/bin/composer
    - php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=prod --ansi

test:app:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Yes this is test - YAYY"

deploy:app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Yes, this is deploy - YAYY"
```

I searched in GitLab docs, GitHub also Stackoverflow. I found solutions but already same.

I tried;

- sleep 60s
- remote MySQL server
- pdo, pdo_mysql enough I know but I download mysqli
- add --env=prod for doctrine:schema:create
- add seprate job. Like build:mysql and build:app (actually I don't know how can I get container ip address)
- also I check some Laravel questions but those didn't work.

Should I install MySQL server to inside the container? Is this a good idea for CI? Or, do I have to install a dependencies for this container like libmysql-dev?

Actually if you have a good example for (symfony, mysql and gitlab CI) that I can look that, let me know.

## Answer

I solved but actually I am not sure how I did. I just add

```
DATBASE_URL: mysql://<user>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<db_name>
```

Could you guide me about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your application searches for this ENV variable and uses it if it is present: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html

*"To get started, configure the DATABASE_URL environment variable"*

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I added APP_ENV but I didn't add DATBASE_URL. I just tried and worked :)

Comment: Cool, feel free to mark the answer as correct and upvote if you like ;)